# Not Able to Cast the Object to Custom Object

Tags: java, generics, resttemplate

I have the APIResponse class which extends the Object class like `<T extends Object>` but while getting the response body from the rest template getting the data into the Object class, not to the Book class.

If I try to fetch the data into the Book class it gives the null.

**I have tried** typecasting the response in The Book Object but no success.
ex.`ApiResponse<Book>`.

```java
public void testCreate(){
    ClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory());
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(factory);
    BookDto bookDto = new BookDto("Pranav","dummy","dummy");
    String url = "http://localhost:9090/books";

    HttpEntity<BookDto> httpEntity = getHttpEntity(bookDto);

    ResponseEntity<Object> book = restTemplate.exchange(url,HttpMethod.POST,httpEntity,Object.class);

        //Able to Get the response body in Object but if I try to change it to the Book the response body is coming null.
  }

    private HttpEntity<BookDto> getHttpEntity(BookDto bookDto) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        headers.set("Accept",MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        return new HttpEntity<>(bookDto,headers);
    }

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class APIResponse<T extends Object> implements Serializable {

  /**
   * status & message fields have not setter. They are assigned value when
   * initial by APIStatus parameter
   */
  private int status;
  private String message;
  private T data;

  public APIResponse(APIStatus apiStatus, T data) {

    if (apiStatus == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("APIStatus must not be null");
    }

    this.status = apiStatus.getCode();
    this.message = apiStatus.getDescription();
    this.data = data;
  }

  public int getStatus() {
    return status;
  }

  public String getMessage() {
    return message;
  }

  public T getData() {
    return data;
  }

  public void setData(T data) {
    this.data = data;
  }
}
```

```java
public enum APIStatus {
  // Common status
  OK(200, null);
  private final int code;
  private final String description;

  private APIStatus(int s, String v) {
    code = s;
    description = v;
  }

  public int getCode() {
    return code;
  }

  public String getDescription() {
    return description;
  }
}
```

```java
@Component
public class ResponseUtil {

  private APIResponse<Book> createResponse(APIStatus apiStatus, Object data) {
    return new APIResponse(apiStatus, data);
  }
  // base method
  public ResponseEntity<APIResponse<Book>> buildResponse(APIStatus apiStatus, Object data, HttpStatus httpStatus) {
    return new ResponseEntity(createResponse(apiStatus, data), httpStatus);
  }

  public ResponseEntity<APIResponse<Book>> successResponse(Object data) {
    return buildResponse(APIStatus.OK, data, HttpStatus.OK);
  }
}
```

```java
@RestController
public class BookController {

  @Autowired
  BookService bookService;

  @Autowired
  protected ResponseUtil responseUtil;

  @GetMapping("/books")
  ResponseEntity<APIResponse<Book>> read(){
    return responseUtil.successResponse(bookService.findAll());
  }
}
```

I expect the response body result into the Book Object, not to the General Object class.

Comment: can you show the JSON response?

Comment: {status=200, data={id=3, author=dummy, category=dummy, description=dummy}} if i try to print System.out.println(book.getBody());

Comment: Why are you using Object.class and ResponseEntity<Object> if what you want is a ResponseEntity<ApiResponse<Book>>? How could the RestTemplate and Jackson know that it's what you want if you just tell them: just give me an Object.

Comment: I am not good at the generics but as per my knowledge ApiResponse is Extending the Object calss<T extends Object> and  to get the response in the form Book we need to  Do the typecast it to the Book like ApiResponse<Book> am I right  @JB Nizet

Comment: No. If you don't tell te RestTemplate that it should deserialize the JSON to an ApiResponse<Book>, it can't possibly know. So it will just create whatever it wants that is an Object (everything is an Object). Probably a Map. And you can't cast a Map (or any other object that is not an ApiResponse) to an ApiResponse. Every ApiResponse is an object, but every object is not an ApiResponse.

Comment: can you please guide me to Resolve this @JB

Comment: How about just... reading the documenation? https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#exchange-java.lang.String-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-org.springframework.http.HttpEntity-org.springframework.core.ParameterizedTypeReference-java.lang.Object...-

Comment: It solved my issue Thanks @JB Nizet we can do something like this ParameterizedTypeReference<APIResponse<Book>> myBean =
      new ParameterizedTypeReference<APIResponse<Book>>() {};

    ResponseEntity<APIResponse<Book>> book = restTemplate.exchange(url,HttpMethod.POST,httpEntity,myBean);